# Background on Activity doesn't appear to be showing

Tags: java, android

I've got a background image file called plan.jpg which is situated in drawable-mdpi.

[image]

I've got the following xml to display the background:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/plan"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.anothertest.DrawPlan
        android:id="@+id/drawPlan1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </com.example.anothertest.DrawPlan>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Are there any other steps i need to undertake?

Comment: Are you calling `setContentView(R.layout.main)` in your java class ?

Comment: Are you sure your `DrawPlan` is not filling the space and hiding the background?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to have a version of your image for hdpi, ldpi and xhdpi folders.

Comment: I should also stop drinking and do more exercise - But i'm not going to :p - internal project on one device, not required